# update blob column with base64 value PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, blob

everyone.

I want to update a blob column with a base64 value generated from a PDF file without any directory in a server, but I have a ORA-01704 error: string literal too long (Image):

[ORA-01704 error updating blob column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9a7A.png)

Is there a short way to do that with PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE example13.dat 
INTO TABLE EXAMPLE13 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
( EMPNO INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
ENAME CHAR, 
JOB CHAR, 
MGR INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
SAL DECIMAL EXTERNAL, 
COMM DECIMAL EXTERNAL, 
DEPTNO INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
RES_FILE FILLER CHAR(60), 
"IMAGE" BFILE(CONSTANT "ORDIMGDIR", RES_FILE) 
)
```